# Manipulate linux workspaces with scripts

Tags: linux, desktop-environment, .desktop

I want to write a script(s) that lets me manipulate Linux workspaces on my computers. I'm looking for compatibility with EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Managers. I currently use `wmctrl` to move existing editor windows to desired workspace(s) with a script.

Now I would like to be able to get a list of current workspaces, so I can compare to my desired workspaces and be able to move to, add, or delete workspaces as necessary -- and do it all with scripts and not GUI tools or keyboard commands.

I've tried various search terms, but the best I can seem to find apply to Mac OS and that is using an unmaintained program.

Comment: If you would use i3 WM, it has its own way to "automate" things via `i3-msg`, ie. the WM has a management unix socket open where it listens for its own commands.

Comment: I will look into that, but I was hoping to not have to drop WindowMaker. And, I was hoping to find a solution that would also work in XFCE.

Answer (score 1):

A current list of workspaces is available from `wmctrl` using the `-d` option, where the `*` character in the output indicates the current workspace. For example, from my system with Xfce:

```
[David@Fedora64 ~]$ wmctrl -d
0  * DG: 1920x1080  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,24 1920x1032  Workspace 1
1  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,24 1920x1032  Workspace 2
2  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,24 1920x1032  Espacio de Trabajo 3
3  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,24 1920x1032  Workspace 4
4  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,24 1920x1032  Arbeitsplatz 5
5  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,24 1920x1032  Workspace 6
```

From there, you can parse out things of interest, like the list of workspace names, with `sed` or whatever.

Regarding workspace creation and deletion, I'm unaware of a way to effect a particular workspace, like specifically creating a workspace between two existing workspaces. However, the number of workspaces can be changed using `xdotool`. For example, if you currently have five workspaces, two can be added using the command `xdotool set_num_desktops 7`, where the two new workspaces are added to the end of the list. Similarly, setting a number smaller than the existing number of workspaces deletes the workspaces from the end of the list.

Comment: Yes, I do that in my script for moving text editor windows. One script does get the list of workspaces using that command and some `awk` code. But I cannot use it to actually create a workspace (I don't currently need to delete any, but might in the future). I will look into i3 WM mentioned by @Jiri B, but I currently use WindowMaker and really like it. I was hoping to find a solution that would work with both WindowMaker and XFCE (for work computers).